# How to Manage Assets in yii2 using twig in child template?

Tags: php, yii2, twig

I want to extend my base twig template with some asset bundles and add new assets in child template.

```
{# main.twig #}
register_asset_bundle('app/assets/AppAsset')

{# child.twig #}
{% extends 'layouts/main.twig' %}
register_asset_bundle('app/assets/NewAsset')
```

So I got error "A template that extends another one cannot include content outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the content inside a {% block %} tag?"
So need I to set each asset to blocks? That is uncomfortable when I use asset bundles. Google have no one solutions for this, what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required for a child template to have its content strictly in the [`block`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/block.html) tags. The engine substitutes the parent blocks for the blocks defined in the child.

Therefore, your `main.twig` template should include at least one `block`, e.g.:

```
register_asset_bundle('app/assets/AppAsset')
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

So that the child can override it as follows:

```
{% extends 'layouts/main.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    register_asset_bundle('app/assets/NewAsset')
    {# More content here #}
{% endblock %}
```

Whatever you put into the "content" block in the parent template will be replaced with the content of that block defined in the child.

Comment: I didn't know what register_asset_bundle may to use inside block, thank you!